# WP7 WebBrowser control enlarges text when in Landscape mode

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, orientation

I have a WebBrowser control that is getting content via the NavigateToString() method. It looks fine in portrait mode, but when I change the orientation to landscape, the text becomes noticeably larger (I'd say about 2 times larger). I'm not sure what's going on. I'm not doing anything to the WebBrowser control on orientation changed. If I change the orientation back to portrait, it looks correct again. Does anyone know what could be going on here?

Comment: It's not imaginary, http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/embiggen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you're using a fixed width for the viewport and this is causing the text to be enlarged as all the content is stretched to the wider screen size when in landscape mode.

If you can post an example of the HTML you're using we could probably say for sure.

Comment: I removed the fixed width on the viewport and it fixed the problem. The text is still a little larger, but not much and is readable in the given area.